# How do I remove an empty matplotlib AxesGrid cell with an uneven amount of figures?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am currently trying to create a grid of 7 figures. Four of them on the first row and the remaining three on the second row. I have used the AxesGrid toolkit (https://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/axes_grid/users/overview.html) from matplotlib to create a 2 x 4 grid. However, the last grid cell on the second row is showed, even when empty. I would like to remove this empty box but would like to keep the same position of the three figures on the bottom row.

I have simplified the code to the following

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import AxesGrid
import numpy as np

im = np.arange(100)
im.shape = 10,10

fig = plt.figure(figsize = (15,7))
grid = AxesGrid(fig, 111, nrows_ncols=(2, 4), axes_pad=(0.35, 0.25))

for i in range(7):
    grid[i].imshow(im)

plt.show()
```

The code above results in the image below.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

call

```
grid[-1].remove()
```

to remove the last cell and if your cell also contains a colour bar add

```
grid[-1].cax.remove()
```

Comment: Thank you for this elegant solution, I seem to have over simplified my code a bit. My original figures also have colour bars and only removing the grid does not remove the extra colour bar. To remove the extra colour bar use, grid[-1].cax.remove(). I have added this to your answer for the next person that runs into this.